# Block / Completion handler memory leak

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks, completionhandler

I'm trying to figure out why the following code is retaining the memory for the 'dictionaryWithData' variable. Can anyone tell me the best way to send back objects through a completion handler, and how to make sure the object is correctly released afterwards?

```
// Convert JSON to dict
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dictionaryWithData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:((DataURLConnection *)connection).data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
//dataConnection.data = nil;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

if (((DataURLConnection *)connection).completion)
     ((DataURLConnection *)connection).completion(YES, dictionaryWithData);
}^;
```

I then release the connection using the following:

```
[connection cancel];
((DataURLConnection *)connection).data = nil;
((DataURLConnection *)connection).completion = nil;
connection = nil;
```

However, I am getting 803 leaks on the dictionaryWithData object when profiling it. I noticed that if I comment out the calling functions code:

```
...^(BOOL successful, id object) {

//[[CoreDataHandler coreDataHandler] createNewEntityOfType:@"TicketEntity" withDictionary:object];

//[[CoreDataHandler coreDataHandler] saveContext];
}
```

Then the memory is no longer held on too. What the createNewEntityOfType function does is as follows:

```
- (id)createNewEntityOfType:(NSString *)sEntity withDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
     id entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:sEntity inManagedObjectContext:context];

     if ([entity isKindOfClass:[TicketEntity class]])
     {
          [entity setNID:dict[@"id"]];
     }

return entity;
}
```

So it maps the dictionary parameters to the relevant entity type (above is a simplified version). Then returns the entity incase the calling function needs it. So the only thing that uses the reference to the original dictionaryWithData object is '[entity setNID:dict[@"id"]];'. Would this stop the original dictionary being released?

Can anyone let me know if I should be using a weak reference somewhere, or copying the original dictionary when passing to certain functions / completion handlers?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new string from the dictionary value instead of setting the dictionary value to the entity?  Then set the new string to the entity.

Comment: Do you mean via NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithString:dict[@"blah"]] ? Would this work, and is there any generic way to support all types via id? Otherwise I will need if conditionals to deal with a loop I run to make the mapping easier.

Comment: Okay I managed to support it using this id temp = [dict[key] copy]; Will convert the rest of the function and get back to you, thanks

Comment: Good luck.  Not sure why your setNID is holding a reference to the whole dictionary, but it could be...

Comment: Hmm I've changed all the setters to take new temporary objects but still the same issue annoyingly! will have to keep digging on this, if you have any more ideas I will be happy to hear them :)

Comment: Have you tried marking the original dictionary as `__block`?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, however, as you can see I call dispatch_async after and by the time that's called the dictionary is nilled. (Just tried again and __block is no longer being set to nil after the dispatch, however, it's still being retained)

Comment: Okay I have been using [dict copy], however, can you confirm if this will work? Or does this just copy the dict object references as opposed to a deep copy which creates new objects?

Comment: I can't say from experience, but I would say that that would not create a deep copy and just copy the references into a new dictionary.

Comment: Yeah I've now done a mutableCopy which should deep copy (according to docs), however, I am performing it here: ((DataURLConnection *)connection).completion(YES, [dictionaryWithData mutableCopy]); and it's still showing a leak like before, although the completion dictionary should be cleaned up after this function ends I think. So confused.